# How to map weak entity hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations, one-to-one

I have the following relation in database: [image]

I have one strong table.

I have one weak table that has one to one relation with strong table. Really it's 0 to 1 relation, because strong table doesn't have always one line in weak table. To identify this weak table is enough the Id of strong table.

And finally I have another weak table, with ManyToOne relation with first weak entity. It needs the id of OneToOneWeakEntity (that also is id of strong table), and his own id. It's like an historical of OneToOneWeakTable.

I want to map in Hibernate, but I don't know how to do it.

Now I have the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table")
public class Table {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_table")
    private Integer idTable;
    private String otherAtributes;

    ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name="oneToOneWeakTable")
public class OneToOneWeakEntity {   

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional=false) 
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="table_id_table")
    private Table table;
    private String otherAtributes;

    ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name="oneToManyWeakTable")
@IdClass(EntityPk.class)
public class OneToManyWeakTable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="table_id_table")
    private OneToOneWeakEntity oneToOneWeakEntity;
    @Id
    @Column(name="own_id")
    private String ownId;
    private String otherAtributes;

    ....
}

class EntityPk {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="table_id_table")
    private OneToOneWeakEntity oneToOneWeakEntity;
    @Id
    @Column(name="own_id")
    private String ownId;
    private String otherAtributes;

    ....
```

}

My problem is when I try to run my application, because I have this deployment error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering package.OneToOneWeakEntity from package.OneToManyWeakTable has the wrong number of column. should be 0
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:502)
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:117)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1518)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
```

How can I map this relation??

Thanks!

**Edit**: I also try with this to map OneToOneWeakTable:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional=false) 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@Id
@JoinColumn(name="table_id_table")
private Table table;
```

In this case, I also have an error when I try to deploy, but a different exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:568)
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:258)
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1518)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to repeat the annotations in the `EntityPK` class, you just need to match simple primitive attribute that represent the compound key of `OneToManyWeakTable`, you should get something like this (note `insertable` and `updatable` attributes, it has no sense modify the association because it is part of entity instance's pk),

```
@Entity
@Table(name="oneToManyWeakTable")
@IdClass(EntityPk.class)
public class OneToManyWeakTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="table_id_table")
    private long weakEntity

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="table_id_table", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private OneToOneWeakEntity oneToOneWeakEntity;

    @Id
    @Column(name="own_id")
    private String ownId;

    private String otherAtributes;

    ....
}

class EntityPk {

    private long weakEntity;

    private String ownId;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="oneToOneWeakTable")
public class OneToOneWeakEntity {   

    @OneToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="table_id_table")
    private Table table;

    private String otherAtributes;

    ....
}
```

Also take a look at some [official doc of compound primary keys](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cpcd/index.html)

**Edit:** add the `OneToOneWeakTable` assuming that you are using JPA 2, in your edit you are mixing annotation. Check the id fileds and attribute that share the entities, must be same type (note that I use `long` for weakEntity attribute just as an example).

Comment: I tried this, but I have the same exception that on the second case.

I think the problem is the entity in the middle OneToOneWeakEntity. If this Entity has an Integer as Id, it runs, and if the relations are both ManyToOne (the 2nd with the 1st entity, and the 3rd with 2nd entity) also runs.